# Compile Spigot artifact to native image using Graal's native-image: NullPointerException

Tags: java, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to create a native image of Spigot 1.15 using Graal's native-image. I'm using the command:

```
native-image -jar spigot-1.15.jar
```

But the compilation fails with a NPE: https://hasteb.in/qujocavi

```
native-image -H:+PrintClassInitialization -jar spigot-1.15.jar --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime --initialize-at-run-time=net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1
[spigot-1.15:12284]    classlist:   6,064.54 ms,  1.41 GB
[spigot-1.15:12284]        (cap):   2,575.63 ms,  1.41 GB
[spigot-1.15:12284]        setup:   4,437.12 ms,  1.41 GB
Printing initializer configuration to C:\Dev\reports\initializer_configuration_20200222_133304.txt
ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSEngineFactory could not be instantiated
Unable to bootstrap registry 'minecraft:entity_type'
Registry 'minecraft:entity_type' was empty after loading
[spigot-1.15:12284]     analysis:  17,393.28 ms,  1.79 GB
Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.Raid.a(net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.Raid$Wave, java.util.Random, int, net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DifficultyDamageScaler, boolean)
Parsing context:
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.Raid.b(Raid.java:481)
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.Raid.o(Raid.java:291)
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PersistentRaid.a(PersistentRaid.java:43)
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.WorldServer.doTick(WorldServer.java:309)
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1076)
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:393)
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:978)
        parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:823)
        parsing com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.RuntimeSupport.executeHooks(RuntimeSupport.java:144)
        parsing com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.RuntimeSupport.executeTearDownHooks(RuntimeSupport.java:121)
        parsing com.oracle.svm.core.graal.snippets.CEntryPointSnippets.tearDownIsolate(CEntryPointSnippets.java:395)

        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:138)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:323)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureParsed(MethodTypeFlow.java:300)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:107)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.SpecialInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(InvokeTypeFlow.java:421)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.notifyObservers(TypeFlow.java:344)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:386)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.BigBang$2.run(BigBang.java:511)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(CompletionExecutor.java:171)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at parsing net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.Raid.a(Raid.java:701)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2582)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:94)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3402)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3204)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1085)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:979)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:197)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:221)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:340)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:310)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError.shouldNotReachHere(GraalError.java:55)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.<init>(AnalysisMethod.java:149)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createMethod(AnalysisUniverse.java:412)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:400)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.WrappedConstantPool.lookupMethod(WrappedConstantPool.java:116)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupMethodInPool(BytecodeParser.java:4285)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.lookupMethodInPool(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:107)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupMethod(BytecodeParser.java:4279)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1656)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5288)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3397)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.<init>(AnalysisMethod.java:147)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.EntityTypes.a(EntityTypes.java:134)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.EntityTypes.<clinit>(EntityTypes.java:16)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.Raid$Wave.<clinit>(Raid.java:794)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.Raid.$SWITCH_TABLE$net$minecraft$server$Raid$Wave(Raid.java:20)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing default of DefaultedMappedRegistry: minecraft:pig
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:225)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IRegistry.a(SourceFile:140)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IRegistry.<clinit>(SourceFile:130)
        ... 42 more
```

I tried to use the `--intiialize-at-run-time` argument including `net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IRegistry` to avoid class initialization at build time but I get the same error.

So my question is how can I compile it to a native executable ?

You can reproduce the error by executing `native-image -jar spigot-1.15.jar` on a freshly downloaded spigot jar on spigotmc.

Comment: Just submitted an edit to your question with the contents of the last error attempt. Always keep vital information inside your question, dont rely on links, especially crucial things like errors.

Comment: what is the graal version?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare it's the latest release: 20.0.0

Answer (score 1):

It's smarter to use jaotc than native-image. AOT Compilation is the first optimization to be adopted in libminecraft, but it's now deprecated due to an incident when it is discovered that libminecraft doesn't work on some machines due to AOT compilation. Also, spygot uses reflection a lot, which isn't very native-image friendly. Consider using jaotc instead. One drawback of jaotc is that you will need both the jarfile and the AOT image to run.

[AOT-Compiled Minecraft](https://mega.nz/file/g2hRmARb#yowzflih0uJlmuRyx-ujlv2srtWPMdTOvSOCqsbm23g)

https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295